# How to inspect and filter USB packets?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, usb, firewall

I'd like to filter USB packets coming from a USB wifi adapter so that the computer can only see specific wireless devices i.e.the "firewall" would filter out everything coming and going to wifi devices which are not on a whitelist. Filtering should be possible as kind of a transparent firewall, but is not a necessity.

Comment: Since it's at the USB level, this might be of interest (and not limited to wifi): https://davejingtian.org/2016/08/04/making-usb-great-again-with-usbfilter-a-usb-layer-firewall-in-the-linux-kernel/ . Source code: https://github.com/daveti/usbfilter . Not tested, appears outdated now.